# How to show the very next div on button click with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below are my elements.

```
<div class="first-div">
   DIV 1
   <button class="next">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="next-div" style="display:none;">
   DIV 2
   <button class="back">Back</button>
   <button class="next">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="next-div" style="display:none;">
   DIV 3
   <button class="back">Back</button>
   <button class="next">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="next-div" style="display:none;">
   DIV 4
   <button class="back">Back</button>
</div>
```

How can I select the very next hidden `.next-div` element and show it and select the very previous hidden element and show it using jQuery?

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().hide().next().show();//hide parent and show next
});

$('.back').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().hide().prev().show();//hide parent and show previous
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yxpc9qr9/)**