# Clicking a button to show next div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onclick

I have a page with multiple divs. I want there to be buttons that, when clicked on, go to the next div. E.g. Div #1 is visible on the page. It has a 'next' button on it. When the user clicks the next button, it goes to another div on the same page that was previously hidden/invisible (set to display:none). [This](https://pebblequeen04.neocities.org/blogfr) is the webpage I'm editing. I'm willing to use non-JS solutions to this if that's possible but I assume JS is the best/most efficient way to approach this?

I was thinking something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856906/how-to-show-the-very-next-div-on-button-click-with-jquery) but copying it didn't work and neither did anything else I've tried no matter how much I modified my code.

I don't know much about javascript yet so it's my fault for trying this before having the necessary knowledge but I'm desperate to make it work haha

This is a highly simplified version of what I was trying to do with my code:

CSS:

```
.entry {
      text-align: left;
      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 1px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-family: Book Antiqua;
      width: 550px;
      height:500px;
      overflow:auto;
      margin: auto;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="entry">

<p>paragraph text 1</p>

<button class="next">Next</button>
</div>


<div class="entry" style="display:none;">

<p>paragraph text 2</p>
<button class="back">Back</button>
<button class="next">Next</button>

</div>


<div class="entry" style="display:none;">

<p>paragraph text 3</p>
<button class="back">Back</button>
<button class="next">Next</button>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().hide().next().show();//hide parent and show next
});

$('.back').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().hide().prev().show();//hide parent and show previous
});
```

I believe the problem is to do with a lack of a parent element? But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain JS solution, so it doesn't require the use of the jQuery library. more lightweight and efficient.

```
var entries = document.querySelectorAll(".entry");
var nextButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".next");
var backButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".back");

nextButtons.forEach(function(button, index) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    entries[index].style.display = "none";
    entries[index + 1].style.display = "block";
  });
});

backButtons.forEach(function(button, index) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    entries[index + 1].style.display = "none";
    entries[index].style.display = "block";
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Really easy-to-understand code. I appreciate this like you wouldn't believe.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to work, but it is a bit fragile since it relies on a very specific HTML structure.  Here's what your code does

- `$(this)` - selects the button that was just clicked
- `.parent()` selects the parent element of the button, which should be the `.entry` element
- `.hide()` - This will hide the `.entry` element that was just selected
- `.next()` - This will select the element that appears after the `.entry` element that was just selected. Hopefully this will be another `.entry` element.
- `.show()` - This will show whatever element is now selected

Instead I recommend doing something like this. First we select all the `.entry` elements once and keep track of the index of which one is currently being shown.

When a button is clicked we either make that number go up or down, and then show the `.entry` with that matching index.  This no longer requires the HTML to be in an extremely specific format and order.

```js
const entryElements = $('.entry');
let entryIndex = 0;

$('.next').click(function(){
   entryIndex++;
   entryElements.hide();
   $(entryElements[entryIndex]).show();
});

$('.back').click(function(){
   entryIndex--;
   entryElements.hide();
   $(entryElements[entryIndex]).show();
});
```

```css
.entry {
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Book Antiqua;
  width: 550px;
  height:500px;
  overflow:auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="entry">
  <p>paragraph text 1</p>

  <button class="next">Next</button>
</div>


<div class="entry" style="display:none;">
  <p>paragraph text 2</p>
  <button class="back">Back</button>
  <button class="next">Next</button>
</div>


<div class="entry" style="display:none;">
  <p>paragraph text 3</p>
  <button class="back">Back</button>
</div>
```